# Browser computing image sizes inconsistent using Foundation

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

As the enclosed image suggests, Three browsers are rendering the same content **very** differently.

Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 (bottom) is collapsing images and computing significantly smaller sizes earlier than 2 counterparts.  Amazing how Chrome just re-sizes the images and creates a half-blank screen although a sticky navigation bar fills the entire screen (as does a bottom background image)

Safari 5.1.10 (6534.59.10) (middle) handles a smaller viewport, but in sort order, with a smaller viewport, computes new image sizes even smaller than Chrome.

Firefox 29.0.1 degrades nicely based on viewport size, but does **not** re-compute the images.
[image]
Am using Foundation (the minified file) version 5

Source HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' align='center'>
      <tr align='center'>
        <td class="modelloframe">
            <div id="thumbwrapper">
              <a href="/uploads/catalog/image/8/3210.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[]" title="3210F - Women&#x27;s-T 80/20"><img alt="Base_3210" src="/uploads/catalog/image/8/base_3210.jpg" /></a>
              <div class="text" id="thumbwrapper">3210F</div>
          </div>
        </td>
```

How can these values be computed so wildly differently?  And why does Chrome really behave oddly

Comment: Maybe is because there is no width in the table. Set a width to the table.

Comment: Nope... had a width='100%' in there and the result is the same.  Chrome has reduced the table to a width of 402px

Comment: Hmmm...ok...in foundation you must put after the <div class="row"> another div like  <div class="small-12 large-12 columns" > . This div is what gones define what type of blocks you would like in a responsive design.

Comment: Meanwhile i suggest to use block grid foundation instead of use table markup - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

Comment: Yep, had that too.  No dice... no behavioural change.  The smoking gun is 'why is one browser acting so wildly different than the other two?  Basically Firefox has it right IMHO

Comment: block_grid is failing wonderfully, as well. their documentation has CSS that is defined as such: .small-block-grid-3 > li none  but the css it generated does not include it!  I've added it in and it's not picking up.

Comment: Are you using SCSS? If yes you must compile it. Or you just editing css?

Comment: just css.  Additional info, with the block-grid, I get a reduction to 141 or 291px.   But you're on the right track.  Block-grid does do the trick, **however** with-out the row definition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

block grid does give better responsive results.  If someone stumbles upon this, beware of downloaded version.  MIne did not have for each grid type the list-style defined to 'none'...

```
<div class="row">
      <ul class=small-block-grid-6>
             <li>...          </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Foundation, you are going to need to follow their structure. After declaring your row, you need to declare your grid/columns. Let your grid be the parent container and you shouldn't need to mess with the position or width of your table.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' align='center'>
      <tr align='center'>
        <td class="modelloframe">
          <div id="thumbwrapper">
            <a href="/uploads/catalog/image/8/3210.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[]" title="3210F - Women&#x27;s-T 80/20"><img alt="Base_3210" src="/uploads/catalog/image/8/base_3210.jpg" /></a>
            <div class="text" id="thumbwrapper">3210F</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The .column/.columns classes contain the necessary floats etc. to maintain your horizontal block ( row ).

Block grids are an excellent resource as well, but if you do not declare them within a column, you will not achieve your desired results.